# Is using ANY (or ALL) faster than checking manually against each entry in the ANY? - postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-performance

Say I want to check

"A does not equal any of the following: A, B, C"

I could write my condition as

`A != ALL('{A, B, C}`)`

I could also write it as

`A != A and A != B and A != C`

I know I'm not really using types correctly here (mostly for brevity) but the idea should be clear. Is one of these faster than the other? I'm not sure how to test these kind of things on databases yet :(

Comment: For the second variant, there are no hard and fast rules about short circuiting in Postgres as well as most other databases.  Not sure about how `ANY` is implemented under the hood.

Comment: NOT A = ANY('{A, B, C})` equivalent A != A AND A != B AND A != C

Comment: A != ALL('{A, B, C})` equivalent A != A AND A != B AND A != C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions should produce the same execution plan, but if you want to get rid of the subjunctive in that sentence, you should check yourself using `EXPLAIN`.

By the way, I recommend that you use the SQL standard operator `<>` rather than `!=`.

Comment: Woah, TIL `EXPLAIN` exists. Thanks!